# Collection of non-overlapping disks is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose that $D$ is a collection of non-overlapping disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $D$ is countable.

The definition of countable I'm using is finite or countably infinite. I believe my proof strategy is in essence correct, but I don't think it's sufficiently formal.

> By density of the real line, there exists a point of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ in each disk. Upon choosing such a point from each disk, we notice that because the disks do not overlap, these points belong to only a single disk. Therefore, we can construct an injective map from $D$ to $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ sending a disk to the aforementioned point of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ within. As $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so we can identify $D$ with a subset of a countable set, which we know to be countable.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with your proof. I actually find it very concise.

Comment: More generally, a topological space $(X,\tau)$ satisfies the *countable chain condition* (ccc) if there is no uncountable family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open sets. Your proof distills to an argument that every separable topological space has the ccc. The converse is false.

Comment: In the first few words of your solution you meant to say "By the density of $\Bbb{Q}$ in the real line", I think. Apart from that small omission, your proof is spot on.